# Link commands in gdb to observe the execution stack

Tags: c++, c, assembly, gdb

I am looking for a program to observe the execution stack of a c/c++ program. Currently I am using gdb for this purpose.

The following command shows the content of the stack:

```
x/12xg $rsp
```

to execute instruction after instruction I am using

```
stepi
```

Is it possible to combine these to commands so that I would be able to stept through the assembly code and observing the stack? If you have another possible solution/program I am looking forward to hear that as well.

Comment: It may depend on what you want to do ("why?"). You could set breakpoints at function entries, you could use print statements to get your information, etc.

Comment: You can use `display` in `gdb`, or even automate it so that it steps through your whole program.

Comment: @Jester unfortunately      `display x/12xg $rsp`    doesn't work?

Comment: `display/12xg $rsp` should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine commands using `define`, like:

```
(gdb) define mystep
> stepi
> x/whatever $rsp
> end
```

Now `mystep` should step and then dump some memory.